# Italic text not recoloured correctly on mobile

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

On the mobile site, italic-formatted words in answers downvoted enough to receive the "greyed out" CSS are properly italicized but the font colour remains unchanged. See [this answer](http://skeptics.Stackexchange.com/a/22539) on [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22538/does-the-uk-has-enough-wind-to-power-the-country-five-times-over) for an example. The italicized text is formatted with standard `*text*` markdown. See screenshot below.

The same issue happens within hyperlinks. The target text is italicized, but black instead of blue. I encountered this within a positively scored answer. The sentence long hyperlink was also bolded, with a single italicized word in the middle. The italicized word was bold, italic and an active link, but not the correct colour. Sorry, no screenshot of this one.

Bold, blockquote, hyperlink, and header formattings (where italics are not present) are rendered correctly.

I'm using the stock browser on a Galaxy S3 running android 4.3 and CyanogenMod 10.2.1. I was not logged in to Skeptics.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Italic text remains black on greyed-out (very low score) answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298884/italic-text-remains-black-on-greyed-out-very-low-score-answers)