# Italic text remains black on greyed-out (very low score) answers

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, mobile-web

When browsing aimlessly on MSE, I came across [this answer](/a/111014/350567)

[image]

It received a bunch of downvotes so it's greyed out (indicating a bad answer). It was delightful to find that there is **black** text among grey text, which AFAIK is not what it’s supposed to be.

No problem on the desktop site, so I've decided that this question should carry a [mobile-web](/questions/tagged/mobile-web).

Happens on many browsers:

- AOSP Android 7 with up-to-date Google Chrome Stable from Play Store.
- Chrome iOS
- Safari iOS

Comment: `!important`: This also happens in [blockquoted italic text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRyAw.jpg), as you can see in this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/556195/191178).

Answer (score 6):

The recent edit to this question brought it to our attention again - apologies for the lack of fixing in the intervening time since the [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tag was added but as you can see in the [recent announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views), we won't be fixing any bugs in mobile views moving forward since we are in the process of deprecating these views in preference for the responsive views.